# How to access an array´s element from hashmap´s values? Java

Tags: java

I´m triying to access all the first elements from the arrays corresponding to the values in the hashmap thay I´ve created. I can access the first element from an array with one specific value but not all at once. Is there a way I can access all the first elements inside an array from the hashmap values? Or even loop through? And then print the value and the first element corresponding to the value? **For example: Print "Something 150".**

This is what I´ve tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
    map.put("Something", new int[] {150, 2, 3});
    map.put("Something2", new int[] {1, 2, 3});
    //System.out.print(map.get("Something")[0]); //This works, and I get the first value from the array corresponding from the key "Something".

    System.out.println(map.values()[0]);//In this line I get this error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Collection<int[]>Java(536871062)

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map.values()` returns a `Collections<int[]>` on which we can stream and get the first element from each array:

```
int[] firstElements = map.values().stream().mapToInt(value -> value[0]).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstElements)); //Prints: [1, 150]
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question, how could I print the value and the first element in the array corresponding to the value? For example: "Something 150".

Comment: If you just want to print something, you can use this: `map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value[0]));`